# Optimise comparison between two lists, giving indices that differ

Tags: python, list, optimization

I have three lists: old, new and ignore. old and new are lists of strings. ignore is a list of indices that should be ignored if they do not match. The objective is to create a list of indices which are different and not ignored.

old and new may contain a different number of elements. If there is a difference in size between old and new the difference should be marked as not matching (unless ignored).

My current function is as follows:

```
def CompareFields( old, new, ignore ):
  if ( old == None ):
    if ( new == None ):
      return [];
    else:
      return xrange( len(new) )
  elif ( new == None ):
    return xrange( len(old) )

  oldPadded = itertools.chain( old, itertools.repeat(None) )
  newPadded = itertools.chain( new, itertools.repeat(None) )
  comparisonIterator = itertools.izip( xrange( max( len(old ) , len( new ) ) ), oldPadded, newPadded )
  changedItems = [ i for i,lhs,rhs in comparisonIterator if lhs != rhs and i not in ignore ]
  return changedItems
```

The timings of the various options I have tried give the following timings for 100,000 runs:

```
[4, 9]
CompareFields: 6.083546
set([9, 4])
Set based: 12.594869
[4, 9]
Function using yield: 13.063725
[4, 9]
Use a (precomputed) ignore bitmap: 7.009405
[4, 9]
Use a precomputed ignore bitmap and give a limit to itertools.repeat(): 8.297951
[4, 9]
Use precomputed ignore bitmap, limit padding and itertools.starmap()/operator.ne(): 11.868687
[4, 9]
Naive implementation: 7.438201
```

The latest version of python I have is 2.6 (it is RHEL5.5). I am currently compiling Pypy to give that a try.

So does anyone have any ideas how to get this function to run faster? Is it worth using Cython?

If I can't get it to run faster I will look at rewriting the whole tool in C++ or Java.

**Edit:**

Ok I timed the various answers:

```
[4, 9]
CompareFields: 5.808944
[4, 9]
agf's itertools answer: 4.550836
set([9, 4])
agf's set based answer, but replaced list expression with a set to avoid duplicates: 9.149389
agf's set based answer, as described in answer: about 8 seconds
lucho's set based answer: 10.682579
```

So itertools seems to be the way to go for now. It is surprising that the set based solution performed so poorly. Although I am not surprised that using a lambda was slower.

**Edit:** Java benchmark
Naive implementation, with way too many if statements: 128ms

Comment: How much faster does it need to be? For your test data, how long are the lists? How long is `ignore` relative to them?

Comment: And what exactly are you going to do with the results? Instead of returning a list of changed indices so that external code can index in with those indices and do something with those elements, have you considered passing in a function to apply to the changed elements?

Comment: @agf: old / new are 22 to 37 elements depending on what I am diffing. ignore is typically about 4 or 5 elements. Typically the function will be called about 100,000-200,000 times for a short replay test. For a full replay test the function will be called about 1,000,000 times.

Comment: @teambob Well, you definitely want low overhead for lists that short. You'll have to time the various answers, but I'd bet on the first one in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For both of these solutions, you should do:

```
ignore = set(ignore)
```

which will give you constant (average) time `in` tests.

I think this is the `itertools` / `zip` based method you were looking for:

```
[i for i, (o, n) in enumerate(izip_longest(old, new)) 
                          if o != n and i not in ignore]
```

No need for `chain` / `repeat` to pad -- that's what `izip_longest` is for. `enumerate` is also more appropriate than `xrange`.

And a more Pythonic (and possibly faster) version of the `filter` / set difference method in Lucho's answer:

```
[i for i, v in set(enumerate(new)).symmetric_difference(enumerate(old)) 
                                                     if i not in ignore]
```

List comprehensions are preferred over `filter` or `map` on a `lambda`, and there is no need to convert both lists to `set`s if you use the `symmetric_difference` method instead of the `^` / xor operator.

Answer (score 1):

make `ignore` as set also.

`filter(lambda x: x[0] not in ignore, set(enumerate(new)) ^ set(enumerate(old)))`

I bet it will be faster than yours overcomplicated non-pythonic try outs (it would be cool if you can measure it - i am curious).

Comment: which translates to what I have written... what's your point?

Comment: You call the `itertools` version in the question non-Pythonic; I pointed out that an unnecessary `filter` on a `lambda` could be made more Pythonic as well. There can even be a performance advantage because there is no per-iteration function call overhead in the list comprehension version.

Comment: I moved my version into my answer as I decided to also mention a simpler `itertools` method.

Answer (score 1):

list constructors are definatly a pythonic thing to do, I would do something similar to this:

```
def findDiff(old, new, ignore):
    ignore = set(ignore)
    diff = []
    (small, big) = (old, new) if len(old) < len(new) else (new, old)
    diff.extend([i for i in xrange(0,len(small)) if i not in ignore and old[i] != new[i]])
    diff.extend([i for i in xrange(len(small), len(big)) if i not in ignore])

    return diff
```

for a fast function, this assumes that all indices above the length of the smallest list will be counted as different and are still checked by ignore.

Comment: From the pydocs I got the impression that `deque` was faster for appending and thus extending, i'm curious to know if i'm right?, as for set I didn't know that, thank you, i'll add it in, as with the generator expressions.

Comment: `list`s are already optimized for constant-time (amortized) appends. It's doing things to the _beginning_ of the sequence that are O(n) for `list`s. For `deque`s, it's doing things to the _middle_ that are particularly slow; `insert`ing / `pop`ing at both the beginning and end are fast, as are `append`s -- but `append`s aren't faster than for `list`s. http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity shows this well.

Comment: Great information, i'll change back to list for simplicity then and bookmark the timeComplexity stuff, seems very useful to know.

Comment: @agf after doing some `timeit` with this function, using `[]` instead of `()` is actually `2x` faster at `2.8` seconds as opposed to `5.28`.

Comment: Good to know; I think that will depend on the Python version and the length of the lists. It also could be that `extend` is optimized when it gets passed a `list` rather than a generic iterable; I haven't looked at the source.